# Fedora 20 Gnome upgrade - cannot login anymore

Tags: linux, upgrade, fedora, gnome

I started to use `Fedora` with with `Gnome 2x`. I started to upgrade to `gnome 3x` when I had some electric energy problem in my build and my machine turned off.

Now I cannot log in any more - message

`Oh No! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. All extensions have been disabled`

If I try to run `yum update` again there is two strange things

1)

```
Error: Package: PackageKit-yum-plugin-0.8.17.1.fc20.x86_64
          Required: Package(x86-64) = 0.8.17-1.fc20
          Installed: PackageKit-0.8.13-1.fc20.x68_64
```

2) Lots of `Package [example] is a duplicate with [example]`

Answer (score 0):

Open your the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>, log in as root and then upgrade your system.

```
yum -y upgrade
```

Then reboot using:

```
reboot
```